# read wordpress user data into a local ms access database

Tags: wordpress, ms-access, vba

I'm a MS Access developer who has a client with a wordpress website. I need a way of reading any new users who are added into the wordpress site into a microsoft access database that resides on the users local machine. 
I only need to add any new records and don't need to write anything back to the site. 
What would be the easiest way of doing something like this? I would sooner do it from the Access side as I'm not very familiar with wordpress, also I would prefer it to be automated so the user doesn't have to manually export from wordpress then import the data every time. 
Any advice appreciated.
Thanks 
Justin

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to have WordPress connect to an Access DB because Access isn't persistent, it's on demand.  The only way I can imagine handling it would depend on Access more than anything.  Assuming Access can using the ODBC connectors installed on the windows system it's running on, you could do the following:

1. Setup the MySQL ODBC Connector on any systems which would run the Access DB you're setting up. I assume the WordPress install is using MySQL.
2. Setup a new ODBC connection using that connector within Access to the Wordpress 
   database (you can use the same connection information stored in the
   WordPress root directory in a file called wp_config.php).
3. If you're connecting successfully, you can then read the wp_users table using properly formatted SQL commands (select * from wp_users, for instance).
4. The function within Access that manages this can either be scheduled to do it periodically while Access is open or just when Access is initialized.  Depending on your needs.
5. You'll have to compare it to a local table of users to find differences if you're interested in all changes, though the user_login is static through normal channels so it's a good key.  There's also a "user_registered" date/time column in wp_users so you could just look for users who registered since your last update/change to the local access table.

I'm not familiar with Access beyond a cursory understanding of it as a data source and some minor development functions, so there may be a much easier way to do it, but this is how I'd do it in any system that needed the user information from Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have started to look into this. I have downloaded the odbc driver and I'm still waiting on the client to get back to me with the login details for the webserver so I can have a look at the config file. The access side of it is fine from my perspective, I'll either use a temporary table or look at using the live table once I can access the server. I'll keep you updated:)

Answer (score 0):

Because Wordpress and Ms-Access live in very different environments, a trick is needed to "marry" the two. Another way we can use:

- Use **IIS as a webserver**, so as not to collide with the port used by wordpress, so don't use port 80. Just use any port.
- Use **ASP to access Access Database** (of course there is a block of ASP code to activate the connector to the Access file, then create a recordset via that connector for record2 and display it to the browser). Call it with the file name: ***recordshower.asp***
- The ***recordshower.asp*** file must be able to be called by the browser.
- After that, go back to a page in wordpress, insert `<iframe src=recordshower.asp width:.... ></iframe>`

So, a wordpress page can display the contents of an Access table, with the help of ASP

Answer (score 0):

I export the WordPress entries to a .CSV, I then run an Excel macro, which is stored in my personal workbook, to open the file from my downloads directory, convert the .CSV to .XLS, and write it to an XLS file in a known location.  I then push a button in my MS Access program to read the entries from the .XLS file (which is externally linked to my MS Access as a Excel spreadsheet) and update my MS Access tables with the data.